# Working with Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, object

I am using the Plugins [Jquery Dropdown](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/) and [ListJS](http://listjs.com/).

The jQuery Dropdown Plugin offers a hide event:

```
$('.dropdown').on('hide', function(event, dropdownData) {
});
```

In this function I am using the filter option from the ListJS Plugin (so when closing the Dropdown a list is filtered):

```
$('.dropdown').on('hide', function(event, dropdownData) {
  hackerList.filter(function(item) {
    if (item.values().Produkt == "Cola") {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
}
  });
});
```

This code is working like it should.

The Problem is:

I would like to use a variable Object value ("Produkt" in this case is an object value):

```
if (item.values().Produkt == "Cola") {
```

How can I change the "Produkt" into a variable?

When just using `item.values().MyVar` it is not working.

Comment: Try using item.values()[MyVar] and should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to access a variable, use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties):

```
var myVar = "test";
console.log(yourObject[myVar]); //equivalent to yourObject.test
```

so in your case do this:

```
var myVar = "Product";
$('.dropdown').on('hide', function(event, dropdownData) {
    hackerList.filter(function(item) {
        if (item.values()[myVar] == "Cola") {
             return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
eval ("$('.dropdown').on('hide', function(event, dropdownData) {"
    + "hackerList.filter(function(item) {"
       +" if (item.values()." +Produkt+ " == 'Cola') {"
       +"return true;"
       +"} else {"
     +"return false;"
  +"}  }); });");
```

Comment: use if (item.values()[variableName] == "Cola")  instead

Comment: Thanks @Gabe ! This is the answer I searched for.